# Select from table, where column is foreign key in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

Even though there is an entry in the database, with this query, I always get 0 entries back

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM saved_food WHERE user_id = ? AND favorite_food LIKE ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("is", $me['id'], $favFood);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->num_rows);
```

the dump is 0
The user_id colum is a foreign key, and shows to the id of the table "user".
I can't see the error here.
Is there a special method for foreignkey values?

Comment: seems you need `%` wildcard before and after question mark following `like` keyword.

Comment: Forget about `num_rows`. You don't need it. It will always show you zero rows.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan no, I even tried it with favorite_food = ?. The output of $favFood is correct. It works on phpmyadmin, with the same query

Comment: @Dharman it works in other files though. And I need to check if there's an entry in the Database

Comment: Try `var_dump($stmt->get_result()->fetch_all());`

Comment: @Dharman I did, and it shows the right values.

Comment: Are you sure the query works at all? It's worth trying in a SQL client directly to compare. Your `favorite_food` column could have things like leading or trailing spaces which messes up the query.

Comment: @tadman I'm 100% sure. I dumped the favorite_food, and it has no spaces at leading nor trailing. I copied the values of the outcome in phpmyadmin, and it found me a row.

Comment: just remove that pointless line, `var_dump($stmt->num_rows);`

Comment: you don't need it "to check". To check if there's an entry in the Database simply fetch the selected data

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: @YourCommonSense this is a MySQL response to his query. There is no such think like a question mark. But I do not understand why you ask me this because I wrote it relative clearly.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No it is not MySQL. It is probably working wit PHP but it is deffinitivly no MySQL synthax.  The Query would be using a concaternation and would be for your information  **"SELECT * FROM \`saved_food\` WHERE \`user_id\` = '".$me['id']."' AND \`favorite_food\` LIKE '".$favFood."' ;"** Have a nice evening.

Comment: @HenryStack please read [here](/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @HenryStack do you *really* think strip_tags() or strval() has *anything* to do with SQL? That's a rhetorical question. Have a nice day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202592/discussion-between-henry-stack-and-your-common-sense).

Comment: @HenryStack Please **do not** advocate using SQL injection as a solution. This is extremely reckless and builds very, very bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error... *facepalm*
I forgot to call ->get_result();

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM saved_food WHERE user_id = ? AND favorite_food LIKE ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("is", $me['id'], $favFood);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
var_dump($result->num_rows);
```

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: If prepared properly this should work.